# When is horizontalalignment =stretch applied?

Tags: wpf, xaml, stretch

Does the horizontal alignment = stretch get applied in measure or arrange? does it affect the actualwidth and actualheight of the object? or does it work in some other way? I can't seem to find any documentation on how it is actually being applied during layout

Edit: after some testing it appears that Width and actual width are not changed by horizontal alignment = "stretch"

I'm wondering if maybe it is applied on render.

Comment: It's all explained in the Remarks section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

"When the Height and Width properties are explicitly set on an object, these measurements take precedent during layout and can cancel the typical effects of setting HorizontalAlignment to Stretch.

Canvas does not use HorizontalAlignment when composing layout, because Canvas is based on absolute positioning. In general, the value of HorizontalAlignment is potentially treated differently by any given object that is capable of having one or more FrameworkElement objects as child content."

but it doesn't specify whether the stretch actually changes the width or actualwidth or whether it just overrides it. Anyway it overrides it as far as I can tell, leaving width and actualwidth alone.